# Is there a conditional command in applescript that lets the user quit the app

Tags: command, applescript, conditional-statements

Is there a conditional command in applescript that lets the user quit the app.  I turned my applescript to an app using automator.  However, the script is set to run constantly until its cycled through hundreds of scripts.  Is there a conditional command statement that I can use that will end the application while its running?

```
property MyUserName : ""

if MyUserName is "" then

    display dialog "User Name:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue…"} default button 2
    copy the result as list to {button_pressed, text_returned}
    set {returnedText, returnedButton} to the result as list ---> {"some text", "OK"}
    if button_pressed is "Cancel" then
        beep
        return
    end if

    if text_returned is not "" then set MyUserName to text_returned

    say "Hello," using "Karen"
    say (returnedText) using "karen"
else

    display dialog "Stored user name: " & MyUserName buttons {"Ok"} default button 1 with icon 1

end if



say "For your information, please start the Amuse App everytime you log on... and I will speak to you at random times during your visit with me." using "Karen"

delay 20



try
    repeat 105 times
        set pathToMyFolderOnDesktop to ("Macintosh HD:Users:jr:Desktop:") & "Dsource:" as alias
        set rnd to (random number from 1 to 105)
        set rndFileName to (rnd as text) & ".scpt"
        set FullPath to pathToMyFolderOnDesktop & rndFileName as text
        set myScript to load script (FullPath as alias)
        run script myScript
    end repeat


on error the error_message number the error_number

    display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    return

end try
```

Comment: Do you want a way for the user to quit the script mid execution, e.g. CMD + Q?

Comment: Command Q doesn't work.  What I am wanting to know is basically is there some code that I can put in the script like:  If user hits such and such then end program.

Comment: Sure, think i understand, but perhaps you could include some of your code in the question, this will help find an answer.  There may be a simple way to re-write it to allow a user interrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
display dialog "Shall I proceed?" buttons {"Quit", "Proceed"} default button 2 giving up after 10
if button returned of result is "Quit" then tell me to quit
```

It's using `giving up after 10` which means that that the script proceeds after 10 seconds when the user does not press any button.

To quit it from outside isn't so easy when it's an automator app because they look all the same to the system so you can't really use the application name to tell it to quit. Maybe one could use the full path, like:

```
tell application "/Volumes/Applications/MyAutomatorApp.app" to quit
```

(you can drag your automator app into the script to paste in the full path)

Comment: And if I have saved the script as an app with applescript editor?  Would there be any difference?

Comment: Not really, it's the same with AS-App

Comment: So command Q doesn't' work with and AppleScript app either.  Basically, I would have to use Xcode.

Comment: Did you try to quit it with the full path?

Comment: No, cause - its a non option to quit at their leisure. It's just something I'm doing to keep my mind occupied.  Everything works except for that so it's not a big deal really.